# Teradata character to date conversion

Tags: date, casting, teradata

I have a string associated with date in ‘Teradata’ tables

```
Var1=09OCT2017-EMRT
```

I need to extract the date from the above string in ‘mm/dd/yyyy’ format

I tried the following

```
 Cast(cast(substr(var1,1,9) as char(20)) as date format    ‘mm/dd/yyyy’) as date
```

I am getting error as ‘invalid date supplied for var1’

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a format matching the input string:

```
To_Date(Substr(var1,1,9), 'ddmonyyyy')
```

returns a DATE.

If you want to cast it back to a string:

```
To_Char(To_Date(Substr(var1,1,9), 'ddmonyyyy'), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```